# Rock Paper Scissors result

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that lets the user choose to play rock, paper or scissors. Once they choose what they want to play and the amount of games that they want to play, they will be told if they won or lost.

I want to tally up the amount of times they won or lost, but instead it just prints after each round. Is there a way that I can make it print after the game is completed? I want to show the user the outcome overall at the end

```
from random import randint 

def main():
  games = int(input("How many games would you like to play?"))
  while games > 0:
    games -= 1
    comp = computer()
    choice = user()
    print("You played", choice, "and the computer played", comp)
    winner(comp, choice)



def computer():
  comp = randint in range (0,3)
  if comp == 0:
    comp = 'rock'
  elif comp == 1:
    comp = 'paper'
  elif comp == 2:
    comp = 'scissors'
  return comp

def user():
  choice = int(input("choose 0 for rock, 1 for paper, or 2 for scissors: "))
  if choice == 0:
    choice = 'rock'
  elif choice == 1:
    choice = 'paper'
  elif choice == 2:
    choice = 'scissors'
  else:
    print("invalid input")
  return choice


def winner(comp, choice):
  tie = 0
  win = 0 
  lose = 0
  while True:
    if choice == "rock" and comp == "rock":
      result = 'tie'
      tie += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'rock'and comp == 'scissors':
      result = "you win"
      win += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'rock' and comp == 'paper':
      result = "you lose"
      lose += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'paper' and comp == 'paper':
      result = 'tie'
      tie += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'paper' and comp == 'scissors':
      result = 'you lose'
      lose += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'paper' and comp == 'rock':
      result = 'you win'
      win =+ 1
      break
    elif choice == 'scissors' and comp == 'scissors':
      result = 'tie'
      tie += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'scissors' and comp == 'paper':
      result = 'you win'
      win += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'scissors' and comp == 'rock':
      result = 'you lose'
      lose +=1
      break
    else:
      print("error")
      break
  print(result)
  print("you won", win,"times, and lost", lose,"times, and tied", tie,"times.")


main()
```

Comment: Are all these questions coming from assignments?

Comment: Remember that it's polite to accept answers if they are useful...

Comment: yes they are. I didn't realize you could do that, thanks

Comment: I'm taking this class online and the professor doesn't really teach much. The class has been delayed twice already because no one understands the concepts

Comment: Well, at least it appears that you are trying to write the necessary code, which means we can help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Declare globals for the `win`, `lose` and `tie` counters
- `randint(0, 2)` is how you get random integer
- It's `+=` and not `=+`

There are couple of mistakes. I added a comment `# CORRECTION` at the respective lines.

```
from random import randint 

tie = 0
win = 0 
lose = 0

def main():
  games = int(input("How many games would you like to play?"))
  while games > 0:
    games -= 1
    comp = computer()
    choice = user()
    print("You played", choice, "and the computer played", comp)
    winner(comp, choice)



def computer():
  # CORRECTION: randint in range (0,3) always return FALSE. BELOW IS THE CORRECT WAY
  comp = randint(0, 2)
  if comp == 0:
    comp = 'rock'
  elif comp == 1:
    comp = 'paper'
  elif comp == 2:
    comp = 'scissors'
  return comp

def user():
  choice = int(input("choose 0 for rock, 1 for paper, or 2 for scissors: "))
  if choice == 0:
    choice = 'rock'
  elif choice == 1:
    choice = 'paper'
  elif choice == 2:
    choice = 'scissors'
  else:
    print("invalid input")
  return choice


def winner(comp, choice):  
  # CORRECTION: MAKE ALL THE COUNTERS GLOBAL
  global tie
  global win
  global lose 

  while True:
    if choice == "rock" and comp == "rock":
      result = 'tie'
      tie += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'rock'and comp == 'scissors':
      result = "you win"
      win += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'rock' and comp == 'paper':
      result = "you lose"
      lose += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'paper' and comp == 'paper':
      result = 'tie'
      tie += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'paper' and comp == 'scissors':
      result = 'you lose'
      lose += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'paper' and comp == 'rock':
      result = 'you win'
      # CORRECTION: ITS NOT =+ ITS +=
      # win =+ 1
      win += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'scissors' and comp == 'scissors':
      result = 'tie'
      tie += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'scissors' and comp == 'paper':
      result = 'you win'
      win += 1
      break
    elif choice == 'scissors' and comp == 'rock':
      result = 'you lose'
      lose +=1
      break
    else:
      print("error")
      break
  print(result)      


main()
print("you won", win,"times, and lost", lose,"times, and tied", tie,"times.")
```